# How to enable macros

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

Looking for some insight. In Google Sheets I added a series of buttons linked to macros. Works just fine for me and another user. Other users are telling me that they click the button and nothing happens. My current suspicion is that they were asked to authorize macros and said no. Now I can't figure out how they can authorize macros. I tried giving them editor access and that did not work. I then made my son's gmail an editor, logged into his google account, clicked the button, said yes to the macro authorization questions and the macros run fine. This continues to make me think they said no. Anyone know how to either trigger the prompt again or go in and authorize macros?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets macros only works for editors, not for viewers.

Regarding saying no to the authorization request, the way to show the authorization again when it was previously denied, is by running any macro again.

IMPORTANT NOTE: It's very common that when the authorization is requested for first time to a user, it will not execute the script, so warn you users that if they were asked to authorize the script it's very likely that they should run again the macro.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.

Comment: "It's very common that when the authorization is requested for first time to a user, it will not execute the script," Indeed. This is a trap for not-so-young players too!